# PHP SimpleXML add child to each parent repeatedly

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing, simplexml

I have this kind of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <data>
    <stats>
    </stats>
    <params>
    </params>
    <results> 
        <record id='SJDGH'>  
            <item>abc</item>
            <item>def</item>
            <item>ghi</item>
        </record>
        <record id='OIIO'>   
            <item>abc</item>
            <item>def</item>
            <item>ghi</item>
        </record>   
    </results>
 </data>
```

I'm generating a new `<item>` for every `<record>` in `<results>` in a loop:

```
 // $data is SimpleXml objec from XML above
 foreach ($data->results->record as $record)
 {
   $newitem = 'New item!'.time().$record->attributes()->id;
 }
```

Somehow in this loop i need to change the SimpleXML object (`$data`) to contain new items in every `<record>`.

is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed a little guessing, but this might what you're looking for:

```
$records = $data->results->record;

foreach($records as $record)
{
    $value = sprintf('New Item! %s / id:%s', time(), $record['id']);
    $record->item[] = $value;
}

$data->asXML('php://output');
```

[See it in action.](http://eval.in/private/644d1ab0dd27bf)

Answer (score -1):

I think you might want to use addChild.

Check it out here: http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.addchild.php